# Using both continuous and categorical predictors in Exact logistic regression in SAS

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

I was working with a data set which has small samples. So it was giving me the warning of "The validity of model fit is questionable" for proc logistic.

Then I tried using Exact logistic regression as follows. V2 and V6 are continuous. V1,V3,V4 and V5 are class variables. But it doesn't give me the exact estimates for all these variables. The output exact estimates of class variables are missing. Can't we use continuous variables in this way? Also can't we get the odd ratios using Exact logistic regression in SAS?

```
`proc logistic data=dat1 descending;
 class v1 v3 v4 v5;
 model y1=v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6;
 exact v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6/estimate=both;
 run;'
```

Any help will be really appreciate. Thank you.